# Python Decorator Inheritance issue

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

```
class Foo():
    help_message = ""

    def Help_Decorator(func):
        def wrapper(data, context, caller):
            try:
                if data[0] == "help":
                    return(help_message) #<--- cannot access this locally
                else:
                    return func(data,context,caller)
            except:
                return func(data,context,caller)
    return wrapper

class Bar(Foo):
    help_message = "A real help message!"
    @foo.Help_Decorator
    def Run(data,context,caller):
        pass
```

How can I access Bar's help_message from within my Help_Decorator without passing it as a parameter in `Run`?

Comment: You can't. `foo.Help_Decorator` is only getting a function as its argument, and that function doesn't have any reference to `Bar` which you could use to access `Bar.help_message`.

Comment: Why is the first argument to `Run` `data`? It should be `self`. In any case, now that instance will be passed to the *first argument*, so `data.help_message` *should work*, but it seems like you fundamentally are not understanding class definitions

Comment: Like this will *never work*. Try just doing `def foo(self): print(help_message)` inside `class Foo`.

Comment: Given your descriptions, it sounds like you just want regular functions in a module. There seems to be no use for classes here

Answer (score 2):

Since `Run` is an instance method, `data` is a `Bar` instance.  Normally this would be called `self` by convention, but giving it a different name doesn't change the semantics of the function call.

You should therefore be able to access `data.help_message` in your `wrapper` function.  (I would also expect that `data[0]` gives you a `TypeError` unless `Bar` has implemented `__getitem__`.)

If your intent is to call `Run` on the class instead of an instance, it shouldn't be defined as an instance method.  Make it a class method:

```
class Bar(): 
    help_message = "A real help message!" 

    @classmethod
    @foo.Help_Decorator
    def Run(cls, data, context, caller): 
        pass
```

and in your wrapper now you can do:

```
    def Help_Decorator(func):
        def wrapper(cls, data, context, caller):
            try:
                if data[0] == "help":
                    return(cls.help_message)
                else:
                    return func(cls, data, context, caller)
            except:
                return func(cls, data, context, caller)
    return wrapper
```

Note that there is *no need* for `Help_Decorator` to be a method of either `Foo` or `Bar`.

All together:

```
class Foo():
    help_message = ""

    def Help_Decorator(func):
        def wrapper(cls, data, context, caller):
            try:
                if data[0] == "help":
                    return(cls.help_message)
                else:
                    return func(cls, data, context, caller)
            except:
                return func(cls, data, context, caller)
        return wrapper

class Bar(Foo):
    help_message = "A real help message!"

    @classmethod
    @Foo.Help_Decorator
    def Run(cls, data, context, caller):
        return "derp"

print(Bar.Run(["help"], 1, 0))
```

prints:

```
A real help message!
```

Ripping `Foo` out of the code completely produces the same exact result; there is no need for any kind of inheritance relation between the place where `Help_Decorator` is implemented and the class whose methods it decorates:

```
def Help_Decorator(func):
    def wrapper(cls, data, context, caller):
        try:
            if data[0] == "help":
                return(cls.help_message)
            else:
                return func(cls, data, context, caller)
        except:
            return func(cls, data, context, caller)
    return wrapper

class Bar:
    help_message = "A real help message!"

    @classmethod
    @Help_Decorator
    def Run(cls, data, context, caller):
        return "derp"

print(Bar.Run(["help"], 1, 0))
```

Comment: data[0] is part of my initial functions arguments and does not return a TypeError. I'm not instantiating any instances of these classes.

Comment: @Sitruc **then why is it a class, and how do you expect the function to have access to the class variables?**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because it's inheriting many methods from the base class. I've simplified this example greatly from the real code.

Comment: @Sitruc again, **how do you expect the function to have access to the class/instance state?** You are not using classes correctly.

Comment: @Sitruc you might want to make it a `@classmethod` so that it receives `cls` as the first argument.  Making it an instance method and then passing something that's not an instance as the first arg is (a) unkind to anyone else trying to understand your code (b) counterproductive to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Samwise I've done this, and it kind of works but it only gets the help message from Foo. I was hoping that I could have inherited the decorator as well but it doesn't seem to be the case. :/

Comment: You have to get `cls.help_message`.  `cls` should be `Bar` if the function is a classmethod defined on `Bar`.

Comment: @Samwise This would work great but bar doesn't seem to inherit the decorator so the only way i'm able to call it is from *Foo.Help_Decorator which obviously gets Foos help_message

Comment: No, that's not how that works.  You don't have to "inherit" the decorator, because the appropriate class is passed as an argument to `wrapper`.  It's not clear that these classes should be related by inheritance at all; the decorator seems like it should just be its own function.

Comment: @Samwise not sure the `@classmethod` decorator is going to work here correctly.

Comment: Tested it and it needs to come first.  Decorator ordering is always confusing.  @Sitruc I updated this with actual working code and sample output.  Run it and tell me it doesn't work.  :P

Comment: @Samwise yep, another way would be to implement your own descriptor for the decorator, and appropriately handle the `__get__`, this change is actually what allowed for the chaining of built-in descriptors, e.g. `@classmethod` and `@property`, see this line: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/135cabd328504e1648d17242b42b675cdbd0193b/Objects/funcobject.c#L885 if you look at the git blame it was added to fix this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue19072 And perhaps more friendly, see the [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter passed to the wrapper is an instance of the Run class, you should add self as the first parameter. Then you can refer to self.help_message and it will return the help_message defined in the Run class.

(Edit)
If you would like to use the decorator as a classmethod then just decorate it as such. Your example would become.

```
class foo(): 
    help_message = "bad" 
 
    @classmethod     
    def Help_Decorator(cls, func): 
        @classmethod 
        def wrapper(cls, data, context, caller): 
            print(data, context, caller) 
            try: 
                if data[0] == "help": 
                    print('helping', cls) 
                    return(cls.help_message) #<--- cannot access this locally 
                else: 
                    return func(data,context,caller) 
            except: 
                return func(data,context,caller) 
        return wrapper 
 
class Bar(): 
    help_message = "A real help message!" 
 
    @foo.Help_Decorator 
    @classmethod 
    def Run(cls, data,context,caller): 
        pass
```

Comment: I should have been clearer. I'm not instantiating instances of either of the classes.

Comment: @Sitruc **then it shouldn't be a class**. The only purpose of classes is to *create instances*. If that isn't what youa re using them for, then you shouldn't expect classes to work for you, as you are encountering here. I am not sure how you expect to have access to the class state.

Comment: I believe you're incorrect. I'm inheriting from Foo to save myself re-writing many functions. How am I using classes incorrectly?

Comment: why would you have to re-write *any functions*? Classes **that aren't instantiated don't serve any purpose** except maybe namespacing, but that can be done trivially with `types.SimpleNamespace` or just functions in a module. If you aren't instantiating anything, what purpose does the inheritance serve?

Comment: edited to include an answer if you wanted to use classmethods and not instantiate

Comment: Because they are singleton data holders. I need different help messages from each. The help message will be wrapping commands. I need all the classes commands to be run from the same naming convention "Run" Yet each Run method needs to behave differently. This is why I'm using classes.

Comment: @Sitruc well then you are going to have to use classmethod's if you want access to internal class state